# Using git to version control the Raspi OS

Tags: backup, version-control

I find myself building up lots of versions of SD images as I incrementally develop a working system.  Is there a way to manage this better, such as by capturing the SD image backup not as a img/gz but in a way that git can version control?

Grateful for any advice on how to approach this with `dd` plus any words of wisdom on the general approach.

Comment: It depends how you are doing the changes? Offline then write to SD or changes on the SD?

Comment: Have you considered a basic disk image, and then applying your changes using puppet or similar confiig management tool. It may take a little more time than burning a new complete image, but it does avoid storing/managing multiple images.

Comment: @ppumkin I'm just making changes to the working raspberry and backing-up externally

Comment: @steve-robillard I haven't considered anything like that.  Could you possibly point to any tutorial or guidance with more detail?

Comment: I would start here http://nofail.de/2013/01/pulling-strings-on-raspberry-pi/ (but assuming you are using Raspbian would just install via sudo apt-get install puppet) I am assuming that the various copies differ in what packages/services are installed and running. With puppet you can create a manifest, store it in github and reuse individual bits (e.g. install git and create a .giconfig file). Puppetlabs also has an entire section devoted to learning puppet - https://puppetlabs.com/learn/ Also several books are available for the beginner I would recommend Puppet 3 Beginner’s Guide.

Comment: The above book covers puppet 3 but apt-get will install 2.7 (if I remember correctly), but if you are just starting out that shouldn't pose many problems. If you want more info let me know and I will convert these comments into an answer to your question (it would help to know how and why the images you are creating are different).

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be somehow different, but I think its worth to try it:

Clone this repo: `https://github.com/Metrological/buildroot` and try to build image with it. It's quite straightforward.

Then, you can make changes to it and keep record with git easily.

That is what I do for my RPI projects and it works great. Performances and very good (better than with Raspbian or Arch) and you have **full** control over whole OS.

Comment: Thanks.  That toolkit looks to go much further than this question HTML5 etc.  But I'm a bit confused as it talks about being loaded onto the Pi.  Does it work by version-controlling the boot partition from the 'buildroot' partition?

Comment: I think you got it wrong. `buildroot` is set of scripts which are in version control system. Those scripts generate system images, including `boot/` partition files and whole root filesystem. You will not have compiled binaries in version control, but scripts that can generate those binaries (this is how it is supposed to work).

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't have any requirements on real external HW (usage of GPIO et al) an alternate approach would be to run the image on kvm/qemu. Then you can create as many snapshots as you need.